# Create a node (vue.js) module including SCSS

Tags: vue.js, npm, sass

I want to create a npm module for other projects shared at our repository. My "library" contains some vue.js basic components and some SCSS. I want to reuse this basic scss and the components.

I do use the same SCSS in my components too. Following an example excerpt from a library component:

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
@import "./src/assets/css/variables.scss";
....
</style>
```

Now I want to reuse this component inside my main project but the sass loader fails by referencing this variables.scss (inside my library module). Well this path obviously can't work. I should do something like "../assets/css/variables.scss" to work both in library build as in project build... what has some caveats too when I use nested folders.

I'm wondering to find so little information about it in the internet. Could some one give me an advice of "how to do it right"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to import your variables sass file to your "sub project".

In that case, when you have built your npm "library" package, you can reference it by package name in the sub project you install it to:

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
@import "library-name/assets/css/variables.scss";
....
</style>
```